# Are my regex just wrong or is there a buggy behaviour in td-agent's format behaviour?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, format, fluentd

I am using fluentd, elasticsearch and kibana to organize logs. Unfortunately, these logs are not written using any standard like apache, so I had to come up with the regex for the format myself. I used this site here to verify that they are working: http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/ .

The logs have roughly this format here:

```
DEBUG:  24.04.2014 16:00:00 [SingleActivityStrategy] Start Activitiy 'barbecue' zu verabeiten.
```

the format regex I am using is as follows:

```
format /(?<pri>([INFO]|[DEBUG]|[ERROR])+)...(?<date>(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})).(?<time>(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})).\[(?<subject>(.*))\].(?<msg>(.*))/
```

Now, judging by that website that is supposed to test specifically fluentd's behaviour with regexes, the output SHOULD be this one:

```
Record
Key     Value
pri     DEBUG
date    24.04.2014
subject     SingleActivityStrategy
msg     Start Activitiy 'barbecue' zu verabeiten.
```

Instead though, I have this ?bug? that pri is always shortened to DEBU. Same for ERROR which becomes ERRO, only INFO stays INFO. I am not very experienced with regular expressions and I find it hard to believe that this is a bug, still it confuses me and any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm not sure I can link the complete config file because I dont personally own these log files and I am trying to keep it on a level that my boss won't get mad at me for posting sensitive information, but should it definately be needed, I will post them later on after having asked him how much I can reveal.

In general, the logs always look roughly like this: 
First the priority, which is either DEBUG, ERROR or INFO, next the date , next what we call the subject which is always written in [ ] and finally just a message.

Here is a link to fluentular with the format I am using and a teststring that produces the right result in fluentular, but not in my config file:

[Fluentular](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/parse?regexp=%28?%3Cpri%3E%28%5C%5BINFO%5C%5D%7C%5C%5BDEBUG%5C%5D%7C%5C%5BERROR%5C%5D%29%2b%29...%28?%3Cdate%3E%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B4%7D%29%29.%28?%3Ctime%3E%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%3a%5Cd%7B2%7D%3a%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%29.%5C%5B%28?%3Csubject%3E%28.%2a%29%29%5C%5D.%28?%3Cmsg%3E%28.%2a%29%29&input=DEBUG%3a%20%2024.04.2014%2016:00:00%20%5C%5BSingleActivityStrategy%5C%5D%20Start%20Activitiy%20%27barbecue%27%20zu%20verabeiten.&time_format=)

Sorry I couldn't make it work like a regular link to just click on.

Another link to test out regex with my format and test string is this one:

http://rubular.com/r/dfXOkQYNXP

tl;dr version:

my td-agent format regex cuts off the last letter, although fluentular says it shouldn't. My fault or a bug?

Comment: Dunno about specific language, but usually square brackets in regex are used to define a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). So `[DEBUG]` would mean, one of `D`,`E`,`B`,`U`,`G`. Might want to try `(INFO|DEBUG|ERROR)` or to match literal square brackets, escape them: `\[(INFO|DEBUG|ERROR)\]`

Comment: So try change `(?<pri>([INFO]|[DEBUG]|[ERROR])+)` to `(?<pri>INFO|DEBUG|ERROR)`

Comment: Unfortunately, its still the same behaviour. Fluentular says it should work, but Kibana only lists DEBU, but thanks for the advice

Comment: Let me know if the changes I provided in my answer help you at all. I think the real problem was you weren't looking at the spaces and the colon explicitly. I tested my `format /` line with Fluentular and it works great.

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied before, I will get another chance to try it on that server on thursday and tell you about the result then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the regex would look if you're trying to match the data specifically:

```
(INFO|DEBUG|ERROR)\:\s+(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s\[(.*)\](.*)
```

In your `format` string, you were using `.` and `...` for where your spaces and colon should be. I'm not to sure on why this works in Fluentular, but you should have matched the `\:` explicitly and each space between the values.

So you'd be looking at the following regular expression *with* the Fluentd fields (which are grouping names):

```
(?<pri>(INFO|ERROR|DEBUG))\:\s+(?<date>(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}))\s(?<time>(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))\s\[(?<subject>(.*))\]\s(?<msg>(.*))
```

Meaning your `td-agent.conf` should look like:

```
<source> 
  type tail 
  path /var/log/foo/bar.log 
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/foo-bar.log.pos 
  tag foo.bar 
  format /(?<pri>(INFO|ERROR|DEBUG))\:\s+(?<date>(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}))\s(?<time>(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))\s\[(?<subject>(.*))\]\s(?<msg>(.*))/ 
</source>
```

I would also take a look into comparing Logstash vs. Fluentd. I like Logstash far more because you create Grok filters to match the type of data you want, and it makes formatting your fields much easier because you are providing an abstraction layer, but you essentially will get the same data.

And I would watch out when you're using sites like Rubular, as they are fairly particular about multi-line matching and the like. I'd suggest something like [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) which gives immediate feedback and you can set `global` and `multiline` matching as well.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it's working now :) So my regex caused the trouble somehow. Unfortunately, since they are not really my own logs, I can't decide whether to use Logstash or Fluentd

Comment: I think it was because you did not explicitly look for spaces or the colon. I was just suggesting that for the future, it's all a matter of preference of course! Glad I could help!